# MySQL getting killed by AppArmor

Tags: mysql

I have copied this link from StackOverflow as it is marked as out of topic there and is waiting to be transfered here. So, here it goes:

Occasionally, without any identifiable pattern, MySQL restarts. There are no entries in the error.log or mysql.log (other than booting and checking tables).

Only thing that I could have identify is this exempt from dmesg:

```
[58129723.252413] type=1400 audit(1405923841.567:549): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" parent=1 profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/dev/tty" pid=12848 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="rw" denied_mask="rw" fsuid=105 ouid=0
[58129724.419314] init: mysql main process (26338) terminated with status 1
[58129724.419347] init: mysql main process ended, respawning
```

Does this mean that AppArmor is killing mysqld because it is try to access it's /dev/tty and the access is denied?

Why would mysqld need to access it's /dev/tty and more should it be allowed by mysqld profile? If it constantly needs access to /dev/tty shouldn't it be killed right away, and not occasionally like this? Period between two 'kills' can be a month sometimes.

Thanks in advance for quick answer

Comment: How about /var/log/syslog?  (/var/log/messages?)  Anything in the mysql error log about "number of processes running now 0"?

Comment: No, nothing as such. What were you pointing at? In the meantime I have added rw privileges for /dev/tty for mysql to see what happens.